# Run JavaScript after data-mage-init / mage.apply() has finished loading

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent

There is a widget loaded by `data-mage-init` that I need to run code after it has triggered the change event on the product options, why it does this I don't know, I commented out the line that triggers the change event but the module still works perfectly.

I need to alter some other things on the page when the drop downs are changed.  The problem is the drop downs are changed on load because `data-mage-init` loads this widget which uses `trigger()` to call the change event on all the select drop downs. I need to define my change events after this runs, otherwise I will have code executing just on page load, instead of when a drop down is changed, which is bad.

I am looking for a simple hook to execute code after ALL mage-init scripts have been looped over and loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not the perfect answer this is a hint.

@Wolfe -can you find a data-bind attribute, if can I can give you a hint.
Knockout Js use render events eg. afterRender, beforeRender like

Then if you can add afterRender event and can call your custom function.
eg.

```
    <span class="counter-number" data-bind="text: getQuantity(),afterRender:setSummeryQty"></span>
```

afterRender:setSummeryQty here call the setSummeryQty() js function,

Comment: Cool thank you I'll try this out and report back

Comment: @wolfe - I also wanted to duplicate value and set action after ko js load, so I have tried afterRender and put my custom js function, its works.

Comment: @wolfe - Have check it

Comment: yep it works thanks :D Now I just have to figure out how to run something enclosed in a require.js module from this method :)

Comment: @wolfe - Good , we have to learn ko js to continue the m2